# How do I change the visible tables in the CPT dashboard?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm really not sure what these screens are called (it's not Dashboard at a glance). When I create a CPT and click on the "All CPT", the landing page gives me: the title of the article, the Comments, the Date. My search is providing fruitless because I have no idea how to reference that page. smh.

What I'd like is to show a table column with the user the article is linked to (via Advanced Custom Fields) and some other stuff associated with the post.

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't have an "All CPT" menu in my dashboard, perhaps a screenshot would help? Keep in mind that adding columns to post lists is on topic, but ACF is offtopic as it's a 3rd party plugin

Comment: Is `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=cptslug` the URL? I think that's called the "manage posts" (or "manage yourcptname") screen. To add columns there are filters `manage_cptslug_posts_columns` and `manage_cptslug_posts_custom_column`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_posts_columns

Comment: If you'd prefer a plugin to add/sort columns in the control panel, this is a pretty good one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

Comment: Thank you! That plugin is doing the trick. @Michelle